# Multi-language support for home-grown library references in python

Tags: python

I've created a library in Python, and I'd like to make the reference for the library available in multiple languages.
Is there an easy way to do that?
If so, what is it like?
I would like you to teach me.

Addendum: Multilingualism refers to the natural languages that people use to speak in everyday life.

Comment: When you say multiple languages, do you mean eg French and Spanish, or C and Java?

Comment: Sorry, I meant natural languages such as French.

Comment: The Python Standard Library contains a [port of GNU gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) It even contains examples about how to use it. I am sorry, but I cannot write a short answer explaining it, so I just advise you to read the doc, try it, and ask a more precise question if you have problems with using it.